# Find & Replace in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to do a mass find & replace in Microsoft excel. What I want to do is anywhere that there is a period i want to remove the first letter in front of it and everything else after it.

Example: `Matt RyanM.Ryan`

I want to remove the 'M.Ryan' so it just says 'Matt Ryan'. Is this even possible? If so how can it be done?

Comment: you can use this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to read, then write the code which will remove the M.Ruan using regex and then write back to excel sheet. This is for using javascript as a code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `?.*` as the find criterion: `?` for one character before the period, and `*` for all characters after it:

**BEFORE**:
[image]

**AFTER**:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-2)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25653012)

Comment: @veben You have made a lot of 'not an answer' reviews on answers which are perfectly OK. Please review what 'not an answer' means

Answer (score 0):

This will process all the cells on a single sheet:

```
Sub noDot()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Value
        i = InStr(v, ".")
            If v <> "" And i <> 0 Then
                arr = Split(v, ".")
                If Len(arr(0)) < 2 Then
                    r.Value = ""
                Else
                    r.Value = Left(arr(0), Len(arr(0)) - 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next r
End Sub
```